# Unable to get app-scoped bookmark for file - OS X sandbox

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox

I've been scouring the net and Apple help for some sort of guidance on this and coming up short.  I wonder if anyone has run into a similar situation, or might have some insight into what is (or isn't) happening.

I'm trying to obtain an app-scoped bookmark for a file to be recalled in a later session by the application.  I can confirm that the path itself is properly added to the sandbox after being selected by the user, because I can open (and reopen) it during the session when it is selected.

However, trying to obtain a security-scoped bookmark to access it later isn't working.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *bookmarkData = [url
           bookmarkDataWithOptions:(1UL << 11) //NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
           includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
           relativeToURL:nil
           error:&error];
[url release];
```

I've tried it both with `url` generated from the string `path` as well as just testing it with, for instance, the result of the NSSavePanel's `URL`.  (The string `path` is, for legacy reasons, the one I'd like to be able to use.)

I'm having to use the value for `bookmarkDataWithOptions` instead of the constant because, for reasons of some other legacy code, I'm forced to compile with the 10.6 SDK where `NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope` isn't available.

I can confirm that path points to the file in question as "/Users/me/Documents/document.ext", and that the `NSURL` seems to initialize properly (or at least reflects that same path).

The application includes the entitlement `com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope`.

Anyway, this doesn't work. That code results in both a `bookmarkData` of 0x0 and an `error` of 0x0, and the console shows: `ScopedBookmarkAgent: Failed to retrieve app-scope key, aborting.`

If I change `relativeToURL` to be `url` instead of `nil` and change the entitlement to `com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope`, then it seems to work properly — that is, `bookmarkData` at least gets a non-zero value and no error gets logged.  But I'm pretty sure that's not what I want (i.e., a document-scope bookmark).

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To my everlasting shame, it was my fault.

Somehow in moving the project to a different machine for testing and debugging, code-signing for the Development build got turned off.

Apparently this causes things to (almost) silently fail, with no error code and only a cryptic message in the console, and no other indication that anything else isn't working properly.

Leaving this up here in case someone else mistakenly does the same thing.

Comment: Well, I can confirm that an unsigned build causes this. For anyone stumbling here, I was debugging the Open Source [Mac Linux USB Loader](https://github.com/SevenBits/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader), and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello 2019 and beyond Googlers. I encountered the same issue and fixed it by redoing my development certs. Simply uncheck the "Automatically manage signing" and recheck (maybe switch to a different team and switch back).